# iPhone UITableView with a header area

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a view that was created with all of the default `UITableView` stuff, but now I need to add a header area above where the `UITableView` is (so the `UITableView` will scroll normally, but the top 100px of the screen or so will have static header content). I don't see where I can resize the `UITableView` in IB, and am not sure how to do this.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why don't you use the UITableView provided header?. As follow:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
     return @"My Title";
}
```

Additionally you may resize your table view in IB by dragging the borders.

Comment: I need to put more than the text header that UITableView provides.  It's going to be a 100px or so high area with a person's picture in the left side and some details on the right.  The table view beneath the header will be a listing of the person's posts to a company blog.  So that's why I need a header area separate from the UITableView.

Comment: Then the best approach would be to make the table smaller. Make sure the View Controllers property "view" is an actual UIView and not a UITableView that way you can first drag a UITableView to the UIView and then drag the borders to the desired size.

Comment: Still, providing your customized UIView for tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: would probably work in that case!

Comment: The problem with this is that the view doesn't stay anchored to the top of the screen as a true table header would.

Answer (score 57):

You can use `UITableViewDelegate` methods to create a custom header view for a table and specify the height, namely `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. You can add whatever you like to the view. Here's an example that adds a right aligned `UILabel`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.size.width,30)];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, headerView.frame.size.width-120.0, headerView.frame.size.height)];

    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    headerLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:section];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return headerView;

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return  30.0;
}
```

Comment: in ios7, `UITextAlignment` is deprecated, use `NSTextAlignment` instead

Comment: Thanks @indienchild - I have updated it for ARC & iOS 7.

Answer (score 16):

When you add a `UIView` or one of its subclasses onto the `UITableView` using IB (just drag a UIView and drop it onto the UPPER part of `UITableView` of yours), it automatically adds that `UIView` component and makes it the "tableHeader" component.

Each `UITableView` has one `tableHeader` and one `tableFooter` component reserved...

This way the new view would be a part of the UITable, and scroll with it or appear/disappear or whatever you do to the table. You can change its hidden property if you need conditional behavior.

On the other hand, if you want the header view stay put, as the table scrolls, then it is better to make the table smaller and put the header above it as suggested in other answers...

Answer (score 6):

I finally solved this problem the right way without changing the base class.  The one answer to add the view to the parent nav controller is nice but the transitions look horrible.

The fix is actually easy.  The trick is to create custom setter and getter for self.tableView property.  Then, in loadView, you replace the view with a fresh UIView and add the tableView to it.  Then you're free to add subviews around the tableView.  Here's how it's done:

In header:

```
@interface CustomTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    UITableView *tableView;
}
```

In .m:

```
- (UITableView*)tableView
{
    return tableView;
}

- (void)setTableView:(UITableView *)newTableView
{
    if ( newTableView != tableView )
    {
        [tableView release];
        tableView = [newTableView retain];
    }        
}

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    //save current tableview, then replace view with a regular uiview
    self.tableView = (UITableView*)self.view;
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];    

    //code below adds some custom stuff above the table
    UIView *customHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
    customHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:customHeader];
    [customHeader release];

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, customHeader.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - customHeader.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.tableView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This just draws a black screen for me on iOS 6.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to embed the `UITableView` in a `UIView` alongwith another view (which you are referring to as header section).

So, the `UIView` will have 2 subviews. The header view followed by the table view.

- `UIView`(parent)

  - `UIView` (header)
  - `UITableView` (table)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from noodl_es (upvoted), because it provides the functionality and behavior you want, yet you don't have to worry about resizing the UITableView: that is handled for you automatically. However, the solution is best suitable only if the header information pertains specifically to the first section of the table (or if the table has only one section). If the table has more than one section, then the header of the second section will push away the header of the first section when scrolled up, and therefore the header view will not appear to pertain to the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! Can't you use the section variable to specify which section(s) your custom header view(s) appears in?

Comment: @noodl_es I think the OP was trying to add a static ("header") view in the sense that the same view should be visible regardless of how the table is scrolled. My understanding is that the view should be largely independent of the table view, so it would be a matter of adding an independent UIView above the UITableView. I may well be wrong, this is a long, long time ago (it took me 5 minutes to recognize what I had posted here:-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to have your `UITableViewController`

```
@interface MXMTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate> {
/// your table view interface here
}
```

and a xib with you simple `UITableView` defined yet in it, you can do as Mihir says overriding the `loadView` method like this:

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    self.view = mainView;

    [mainView release];

    // Add Header View
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 36)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:headerView];

    // now, move your table view down. Check you nib to choose 
    // the right Y-axis offset
    CGRect f = tableView.frame;
    f.origin.y += headerView.frame.size.height/2;
    tableView.frame = f;

    // Add the table view to the container view
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // Add footer
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.size.height, 320, 125)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:footerView];
    [footerView release];

    [headerView release];

}
```

...and that's it. You have a `UITableView` with fixed header and footer.

PS. You may now use your xib custom views as the header and footer's views.

Comment: f.origin.y += headerView.frame.size.height/2; ? I think it is not divided by two, it is  **f.origin.y += headerView.frame.size.height;**

Answer (score 0):

[Found a solution at iphonedevsdk](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22003-displaying-uiview-over-uitableview-not-displaying-correctly.html#post99111)

Instead of doing this:

```
[tableViewController.view addSubview:viewSubclass];
```

do this

```
[tableViewController.navigationController.view addSubview:viewSubclass];
```