# Adding Stuff above a UItableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Hello I was wondering if anyone can outline how I would add say a UIButton above my table view. These buttons would interact with the table. Would I have to edit the storyboard at all or is this done so programmatically? How?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: You can use the header property of the tableview. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143264/iphone-uitableview-with-a-header-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times I've done something similar to this, I actually added a section with just one row to my table and added the button(s) as subview(s) of the cell. This seems to be the 'standard' way to do this. Apple does this in the Music app.

Comment: Nice Idea. This will be my next plan of action.