# UITableView with paging and a UIView on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I'm having a table view where the cells are the size of the screen. I'm using the paging system. I also have a view at the top of the table view.

When I scroll the first time it scrolls well from the first element (the top UIView) to the next element (the first cell), then I'm scrolling to the next one and everything works well. BUT when I'm scrolling back, it only scrolls back half way (the exact size of the top UIView).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. **Basically the paging system doesn't scroll the right height.**

**Edit**: here's part of my code that *might be* relevant

```
// Enabling the paging system

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.pagingEnabled = YES;
}

// Setting the height of a cell

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
}
```

Comment: And how do you expect anyone here to be any more sure of what you're doing wrong if you're not showing us what you're doing?

Comment: How are you adding the top UIView to the parent view?

Comment: @nhgrif not sure what part to show, I edited my question though.

Comment: @reecon using storyboard.

Comment: Try adding it as a table view header.

Comment: @reecon I tried doing this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5729991/339260) and it gives me the same result.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Make sure that the constraints of the top view are correctly set. Or even reset them to suggested ones.

Comment: @reecon There's no constraints at all. I reset them though. Here's a quick code I made to reproduce: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e4b1fb8dd8121a05957

Comment: This code does not help at all. I would need to recreate the whole project.

Comment: @reecon I try my best to make this easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

- A UITableView with paging enabled will not work as a expected though
  you set the paging enabled to true.
- For a UITableView to behave like a page we have to control  the Scroll of UITableView.
- There is a sample code for UITableView with Paging enabed [UITableView  With Paging Enabled](https://github.com/jayaprada-behera/InfiniteScrollView)